# what grpc c++ `grpc_prefork()` does?

Tags: c++, grpc

In docs of `grpc_prefork()` it is written that

```
gRPC applications should call this before calling fork(). 
There should be no active gRPC function calls between calling
grpc_prefork() and grpc_postfork_parent()/grpc_postfork_child().
```

- what this function does? why is it needed?
- what are grpc function calls? If I have a server that implements some service, and the method of that service is called and not finished, is this a grpc function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, this function is a part of gRPC Core, not gRPC C++. This is an API for developers of new language bindings for gRPC, e.g. Rust, Haskell. If you're just working with C++, then the `grpc_prefork` function does not apply to you and you can stop reading.

`grpc_prefork` is how we deal with the fact that [threads and the `fork` syscall do not work well together](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-fork-in-the-road/). When a thread calls fork, only that single thread is copied into the child thread. In the child process, it's as if all of the other threads in the parent process had simply disappeared, regardless of what they were doing. Some might have held a mutex balancing a tree shared between threads. Some might have been doing I/O. As a result, the state in the child process is a minefield of violated assumptions.

I like to use the metaphor of everyone else in the world but you suddenly vanishing. It might be peaceful for a bit, but pretty soon planes will start falling out of the sky and nuclear reactors will start melting down.

`grpc_prefork` is a solution to this problem. It's intended to be registered with `pthread_atfork`. When a thread (thread A) calls `fork`, it will first run `grpc_prefork`. This flips a bit signalling to all other threads in the process that they need to close all FDs and come to a known safe state (i.e. no holding any mutexes or actively modifying any data structures). Thread A will block waiting for all other threads to reach that safe state.

After that, `grpc_postfork_parent` is called in the parent and `grpc_postfork_child` is called in the child. This puts the planes back in the air and the nuclear plant workers back to work, so to speak.

> what are grpc function calls

This means *any* gRPC Core API. Not many of them are blocking, so it's not a huge concern. The main blocking function that we'd be worried about here is `grpc_completion_queue_next`, which drives most work in gRPC Core.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! We have c++ grpc server and some legacy code that calls `grpc_prefork()` before forking and then `grpc_postfork_child`, `grpc_postfork_parent`, and we have an issue that sometimes after calling `grpc_prefork` our server freezes. You said that if you're are just working with C++ , it does apply, but why? If these functions are not called then how we will come to a safe state in child process?